# Ruby on Rails 3.2.8 & jQuery: Blank javascript function bodies?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

developing my first Rails application here. Trying to get jQuery working in my views, which as I understand, should simply work 'out-of-the-box' with my current version of Rails 3.2.8.

Here's what I got:

- A view called *register#index* (with a controller called 'register'):

  ```
  <head>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", controller.controller_name %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", controller.controller_name %>
  </head>
  ```
- Two JS files being loaded by this view: *application.js* and *register.js*

  *application.js*:

  ```
  //= require jquery
  //= require jquery_ujs
  //= require twitter/bootstrap
  ```

  *register.js*:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  alert("Hello, jQuery!");
  });
  ```

When I load the page through my browser, I can see the jQuery.js files included, and my *register.js* loaded, which now has been converted to:

```
(function() {

}).call(this);
```

The `alert()` call is missing (and doesn't trigger). Why is this blank? Is this a problem with my gem, or a problem with my jQuery syntax?

Some additional things worth noting:

- Gemfile includes `jquery-rails`, and I've run `bundle install` and `rails g jquery:install`
- Even if I put in jQuery other than `alert()`, the function body still shows up blank.
- I have cleared my caches between each test.
- There are no JavaScript errors reported by the browser (Chrome)
- This code is more or less copy/pasted directly from the jQuery tutorial.

**EDIT**: Added how my javascript tags are included in the page.

Comment: Can you paste how are you including these javascript files in your html?

Comment: Hey fkreusch, I added the code for how the javascript files are included in the view above. It's done with one `<% javascript_include_tag %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

So even though jQuery was being loaded in my *application.js* file, it wasn't in scope for the *register.js* file to use (which evidently was being loaded in parallel, probably due to how I referenced it in my `javascript_include_tag`.)

The solution was to make sure than jQuery is in scope for that extra *register.js* file, by adding a manifest comment at the beginning of *register.js* which loads jQuery:

The newly revised *register.js* file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

$(document).ready(function(){

    alert('Hello, jQuery!');

});
```

**NOTE**:

It just so happens I am also using *twitter-bootstrap-rails*, which evidently includes jQuery in its package. When I used the `//= require jquery` includes above, although it worked, it threw an error in the browser:

```
Uncaught typeerror Object#<object> has no method 'popover'
```

To avoid this error, I included the twitter bootstrap reference and omitted the other jQuery references. My *register.js* file as it ended up:

```
//= require twitter/bootstrap

$(document).ready(function(){

    alert('Hello, jQuery!');

});
```

Hope this helps anyone who runs into a similar problem in the future!

- Dave

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are only loading the .js files specific to each controller.  Try changing your `head` to load all your .js and .css files at once and see if that helps:

**application.html.erb**

```
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application-all", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
</head>
```

You also need to change your application .js to include all the .js files like this:

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

If that doesn't work, try moving your javascript out of the  .js file and into your view just to make sure you have jQuery in place correctly.  You would do that like this:

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      alert("Hello, jQuery!");
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Josh. It was a deliberate decision to prevent all my JS/CSS files from loading (by omitting `//= require tree .`) in order to reduce clutter/load times. (Not every JS/CSS file is used on every page.)

Given my tags above, I'm not loading just the `<controller>.js` file, but the `application.js` file as well; the `javascript_include_tag` references both.

My answer might make things a little more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert("Hello, jQuery!");
});
```

Use this script in application.js..
if you get alert, it means your register.js file is not properly included.

Comment: Tried this; didn't work, strangely enough. But I can confirm for a fact that the *register.js* file is being loaded, because I can see it listed under the Resources via Chrome dev tools when I load the page.